# Can't rebind Ctrl-B to Ctrl-A in tmux

Tags: tmux

I've set options to unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and bind tmux on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is not working, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> still is. I've got my tmux config in the right place, as if I change some other option I can see the result.

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix
```

What is wrong? How to make it work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This config works for me. You probably haven't restarted your `tmux` server yet.

From [`man 1 tmux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux):

> In `tmux`, a session is displayed on screen by a client and all sessions are managed by a single server. The server and each client are separate processes which communicate through a socket in `/tmp`.

One method is to terminate everything inside `tmux`, so `tmux ls` yields "no server running …". At this moment the next `tmux` command will start it anew, loading your new config file.

Also read this: [*Tmux not sourcing my .tmux.conf*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66606/108618). According to one of the answers, this should work without the need of restarting the server:

> This can also be done from within `tmux`, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (prefix key) and then <kbd>:</kbd> to bring up a command prompt, and typing:
>
> ```
> source-file ~/.tmux.conf
> ```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was trying to reload my console from which i start tmux, but it had no effect. Executig the command above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand Kamil Maciorowski's answer, to trigger the new config file, you can terminate your sessions with:

- terminal command `tmux kill-session -a` with the `-a` for all
- join your existing session with `tmux a` and using your prefix (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>) to type the command `:kill-session`.

The general topic here: https://superuser.com/a/1161344/268437